# Apparmor driving me nut

Tags: 20.04, snap, apparmor

not way to make some snap running on my office machine (ubuntu 20.04 focal)
I try for example to run drawio (from snap) with no success.

what is strange is that on my home machine (ubuntu focal 20.04) it work fine

`:~$ drawio
:~$ dmesg ...
 
[66878.875894] audit: type=1400 audit(1596226555.076:342): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="snap.drawio.drawio" pid=149103 comm="mkdir" capability=1  capname="dac_override"`

however

`sudo aa-complain /snap/bin/drawio
Profile for /usr/bin/snap not found, skipping`

is there no way to tell apparmor to ignore drawio ?

Comment: I have found a deb of draw.io on their github. removed snap and installed drawio.deb, problem solved, but still dunno why apparmor where so rude.